# C# read/write mifare nfc tag

Tags: c#, nfc

I've searched a lot but I'm not able to find some C# simple sdk that lets me write and read in a nfc mifare 1k classic tags.

Could you give me some help please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which reader/OS are you looking to use? Windows 8 has native support for NFC, but any other desktop OS will require a reader which usually has its own SDK for this purpose.

Comment: I'm using this reader ACR122U, it comes with a few documentation and I'm studying it now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Using the same one, no luck either.

Comment: I've recently found https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp this does seem to help but I'm still trying to figure out how to read the data. Worth taking a look at

Answer (score 1):

Just check my library for ACR122u readers. It also supports insert/discard events. It is so simple to use it. Basically you create a class and register two events to that class. Afterwards, call the Watch function. It watches the changes on your device.

```
//Initializing
NFCReader NFC = new NFCReader();

//Inserted Event 
NFC.CardInserted += new NFCReader.CardEventHandler(...Some function);

//Ejected Event
NFC.CardEjected += new NFCReader.CardEventHandler(... Some function);


//Enabling Event Watching
NFC.Watch();
```

If any change occurs, it calls the related event. You handle what you want to do there.

```
public void Card_Inserted()
{
  try
  {
    if (NFC.Connect())
    {
        //Do stuff like NFC.GetCardUID(); ...
    }
    else
    {
        //Give error message about connection...
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //Something went wrong
  }
}

public void Card_Ejected()
{
   //Do stuff...
   NFC.Disconnect();
}
```

See the related repo and links for more information.

Medium introduction tutorial:
https://medium.com/@hakbas/nfcreader-a-very-simple-nfc-library-for-c-that-supports-insert-and-discard-events-93db29f79b5

Github address:
https://github.com/h4kbas/NfcReader